# How to download the whole genome of an organism from NCBI using R or Python?

Tags: computational-biochemistry

I need to download some of the genomes of human gut microbiome in FASTA format. Anybody has any script to download?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the `bit-dl-ncbi-assemblies` from the [Bioinformatics Tools](https://github.com/AstrobioMike/bit) package.

```
$ bit-dl-ncbi-assemblies

 --------------------------------  HELP INFO  --------------------------------- 

  This program downloads assembly files for NCBI genomes. It takes as input
  assembly accessions (either GCA_* or GCF_*) and optionally a specification of
  which format to download (currently: genbank, fasta, protein, or gff). For
  version info, run `bit-version`.

    Required input:

        - [-w <file>] single-column file of NCBI assembly accessions

    Optional arguments include:

        - [-f <str>] default: genbank
                  Specify the desired format. Available options currently
                  include: genbank, fasta, protein, gff, feature_tab, report, stats.

        - [-j <int> ] default: 1
                  The number of downloads you'd like to run in parallel. Write speeds
                  can become problematic generally with around 15 or more, so a max
                  of 12 will be used to be safe even if more are requested.

    Example usage:

     bit-dl-ncbi-assemblies -w ncbi_accessions.txt -f protein -j 4
```

Alternatively, you can use this code from the [Biopython cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec149):

```py
import os
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com"  # Always tell NCBI who you are

seq_ids = ["EU490707"] # Your accessions go in this list
for sid in seq_ids:
    filename = f"{sid}.fasta"
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        # Downloading...
        net_handle = Entrez.efetch(
            db="nucleotide", id=sid, rettype="fasta", retmode="text"
        )
        out_handle = open(filename, "w")
        out_handle.write(net_handle.read())
        out_handle.close()
        net_handle.close()
        print("Saved")
```